# CSS conditionals for tablet / mobile, not just <!--[if IE]>?

Tags: css, cross-browser, conditional-statements

Ive made a website that renders fine in all browsers, but when viewed on a phone or tablet the body font whose weight is `font-weight: 100;` just comes out to fine.

Is there a way i can write a css conditonal to target mobiles and tablets, similar to the IE conditional ?

```
<!--[if IE]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE<br />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: [Use media queries to target mobiles and tablets](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

Comment: @Vucko: Media queries also apply to desktop browsers.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell, yes I know, but the OP asked about the mobile and tablet devices, not desktop browsers.

Comment: @Vucko: What I tried to say was: If he wants some specific style for mobile devices only, media queries could get him into trouble, because the stylings will apply to desktop browsers too.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell so put a media query for desktop browser that will override the querys for mobile devices. :)

Comment: @Vucko: Obviously I have to do some research, because I have no idea how to surely address either mobile or desktop devices with media queries.

Comment: The answer is clearly stated below and Linus is correct about using media queries.

Comment: OP: Conditional comments don't exist anymore on IE10, so you're targetting IE9-, not IE. For IE10, see [@viewport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use media queries: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Examples (Quoted from Bootstrap's site):

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

Comment: thanks, that a good work arround, ive implemented this code bellow but dosnt seem to work (tested on a ipad mini) any idea why that might be ? @media (max-width: 500px) {
      body {
          font-family: times;
      }
}

Comment: Ipad mini needs an additional media query. This site has the code for all ios devices: http://www.stephentgilbert.com/mediaqueries/

Comment: cheers, i could have gone around for hours and never found that !

Answer (score 1):

OP,

Within your CSS you can do [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to conditionally hide/show/modify elements based on the size of the screen that is viewing them.

#### CSS

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    /* Large desktop */
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    /* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
}

@media (max-width: 767px) { 
    /* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
}


@media (max-width: 480px) {
 /* Landscape phones and down */
}
```

---

Via [Twitter Bootstrap Docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) on responsive design. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are no conditional comments for mobile devices because they should operate exactly the same as desktop browsers. (What I think is a mess by the way. Responsive design is good, but not a solution for everything)

Comment: "should operate exactly the same as desktop browsers" tell me more about how desktops have touch events. `:P`

Comment: Yeah but I think discussing this goes as a little off-topic. There are some reasons to target mobiles, specifically the smaller screen makes it hard to read text depending on the layout, also many CSS3 features make page rendering much slower on mobile.